# Tracking the Processing of New Members

Tags: civimember

As part of our joining process we send out a membership pack to new members. This involves exporting the name and address details to a mail merge to produce a membership card.

What is the best way to track and process these new members? I was hoping to use the membership status but that only works on dates. Would a custom field or a tag or group be the best approach?

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanting to track who was sent something, then I would create a new Activity Type for 'send member pack' and then via a Search  you would be able to add an Activity to any member that you are sending the pack to, and set it to Completed, and hence you know the job has been done.

NOTE: when adding an Activity to lots of contacts via Actions on the Search screen there is a small checkbox that lets you specify whether you are making one Activity that relates to LOTS of contacts, or one Activity for EACH contact. You are welcome to choose, but i would suggest doing the latter option, so you have a single Activity record for each Member.

EDIT: (per frTommy suggestion) You could automate this somewhat by utilizing CiviRules to Schedule an Activity of "Send Member Pack" whenever a Membership is added

Comment: Just to piggyback on petednz's suggestion. You could automate this somewhat by utilizing CiviRules to Schedule an Activity of "Send Member Pack" whenever a Membership is added.

Comment: nice. adding to answer.

Comment: Ah hadn't thought of using Activity & Rules like that. So many features, so little time. I shall give it a try, thanks.